# Confused about AttributeError in Python

Tags: python, class, error-handling, attributes

I am trying to do the following project:

Imagine you have started up a small restaurant and are trying to make it easier to take and calculate orders. Since your restaurant only sells 9 different items, you assign each one to a number, as shown below.

```
Chicken Strips - $3.50
French Fries - $2.50
Hamburger - $4.00
Hotdog - $3.50
Large Drink - $1.75
Medium Drink - $1.50
Milk Shake - $2.25
Salad - $3.75
Small Drink - $1.25
```

To quickly take orders, your program should allow the user to type in a string of numbers and then it should calculate the cost of the order. For example, if one large drink, two small drinks, two hamburgers, one hotdog, and a salad are ordered, the user should type in 5993348, and the program should say that it costs $19.50. Also, make sure that the program loops so the user can take multiple orders without having to restart the program each time.

My code looks like this so far:

```
print "------------------Menu-------------------"

class Menu_Item():
    def __init__(self, num,item,price):
        self.num = num
        self.item = item
        self.price = price
    def __repr__(self):
        return "\n" + str(self.num) + ".  " + self.item + " - $" + str(self.price) + ' dollars'



Strips = Menu_Item(1,'Chicken Strips', 3.50)
Fries = Menu_Item(2,"Fries",2.50)
Burger = Menu_Item(3,"Burger",4.00)
Hotdog = Menu_Item(4,"Hotdog",3.50)
Large_Drink = Menu_Item(5,"Large Drink",1.75)
Medium_Drink = Menu_Item(6,"Medium Drink", 1.50)
Milkshake = Menu_Item(7,"Milkshake", 2.25)
Salad = Menu_Item(8,"Salad", 3.75)
Small_Drink = Menu_Item(9,"Small Drink", 1.25)


Class_Items = [Strips,Fries,Burger,Hotdog,Large_Drink,Medium_Drink,Milkshake,Salad,Small_Drink]


print Class_Items

def take_order():
    count = 0
    string = raw_input("Enter your order")
    order = []
    for a in string:
        order.append(a)
    for food in Class_Items:
        for b in order:
            if b == Menu_Item.num:
                count = count + Menu_Item.price
                return count
            else:
                print "-"

take_order()
```

I am getting the following error. I have tried a ton of ways to make this work and I can't figure out why the compiler isn't recognizing the num attribute. Any suggestions as to why this is happening? Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 43, in <module>
  File "python", line 37, in take_order
AttributeError: class Menu_Item has no attribute 'num'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you accessing Menu_Item here? That's the class itself; the item that you've got from the list is called `food`.

Answer (score 0):

`Menu_Item` is the class. You attempted to access an attribute of the class. Think of a class like a blueprint for a house. You asked for the street address for the blueprint.

In Python, you're supposed to name classes with `CamelCase` by convention and PEP 8. So, `MenuItem` instead of `Menu_Item`. You are also supposed to name variables using `separated_by_underscores`. This way, you can easily distinguish between classes and normal objects.

I think what you want is:

```
for food in Class_Items:
    for b in order:
        if b == food.num:
            ...
```

This way, instead of comparing the blueprint's street address, you compare the actual house's street address. Python ≠ English; the blueprint is always `Menu_Item` and `food` will refer to a house. (assuming you don't explicitly say `Menu_Item = ...` or likewise `food = ...`)

Also, python doesn't have a compiler. It's not a compiled language.

You should inherit off of `object` by convention; `class MenuItem(object):`

The foods would be better implemented as classes with *class attributes* that inherit off of `MenuItem`.

Class attributes are attributes defined in the body of the class. For example:

```
class HotDog(MenuItem):
    price = 1.5
```

would let you write `HotDog.price` and receive `1.5` as the answer.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you

Comment: @brianhalperin if you upvoted and clicked the check mark, I would receive reputation for answering. Reputation is very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

You've got several problems here. Most notably the one pointed out by Daniel Roseman and uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC. However, after fixing that issue you will still have problems with your code.

In `take_order()` you need to move `return count` outside of your for loop otherwise you will return count after the first item is added. You will also need to change the input to an integer or `b == food.num` will never resolve to True.

Comment: uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC's just a temporary name. CrazyPython is my real name (we come from the lands of codegolf.se) :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the useful answers you received, I just wanted to point out that you can solve this problem with a simple function, without having to define a new class (the project didn't require that, according to what you wrote).

To begin with, you can create a dictionary of the items on the menu and their price:

```
menu_items={'1':['Chicken Strips',3.50],'2':['French Fries',2.50],'3':['Hamburger',4.00],'4':['Hotdog',3.50],'5':['Large Drink',1.75],'6':['Medium Drink',1.50],'7':['Milk Shake',2.25],'8':['Salad',3.75],'9':['Small Drink',1.25]}
```

After that, you can create a function that addresses you needs:

```
def total_order():
    total=0
    while True:
        order=str(input('Please enter your order, or type "done" to terminate the program: '))
        sum_order=0
        if order=='done':
            print('\nProgram terminated. The overall total order is: '+str(total)+'$')
            return total
        for number in order:
            if number in menu_items: 
                sum_order+=menu_items[number][1]
        total+=sum_order
        print('The total for this order is: '+str(sum_order)+'$\n')
total_order()
```

The function keeps executing until you type the word 'done', and it prints the amount of money spent for each order, as well as the total amount of money spent (for all the orders together).